# prevent scrolling to top of page with iscroll?

Tags: javascript, jqtouch, scrollto

I use jqtouch and iscroll for my app.
I load all pages with ajax and when I go back from a ajax loaded page to the index (menulist) page, that page scrolls to the top.
How can I prevent this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to set the option checkDOMChanges to false?

Comment: Hi Ralf, yes I tryed, but it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a boolean option called topOnDOMChanges

```
var scroll = new iScroll(contentid, {
                          desktopCompatibility: true,
                          bounce: true,
                          momentum: true,
                          checkDOMChanges: false,
                          topOnDOMChanges: false
                        });
```

From the Beedesk fork of JQTouch https://github.com/beedesk/jQTouch/blob/master/demos/main/index.html

Comment: I would have a look at their demos. I'm using their iScroll implementation almost verbatim and mine doesn't scroll to top when changing panes. JQT is kinda fickle though.